# visual studio right click missing find all refences and go to definition disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010, suddenly from right click menu  Go to Defination option is disabled and even F12 does not work.  Find all referneces option is missing from the menu... i use them a lot, how can I get them work

Comment: What kind of file do you have open? Or is it all of them?

Comment: I have .cs file opened in any of the .cs or .aspx.cs files it is not working.

Comment: Take a look to: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5562f8f3-8fee-4080-83c1-7dbba8dadd4a/go-to-definition-is-disabled-in-visual-studio

Comment: I encountered the same issue with VS2013 Ultimate.

Answer (score 44):

I had the same problem with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Premium.

Fixed it by following the steps:

1. Close your solution.
2. Delete hidden .suo file in folder where your solution's .sln file exists.
3. Open your solution.
4. Rebuild your solution.

F12 should now work.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The suggestion from msbyuva's MSDN link solved it for me -- my Text Editor -> File Extension was set to Visual Basic not C++.

Comment: I would recommend to rename the file rather than deleting it, not just for this case, but for any case of removing a file that causes trouble

Answer (score 6):

To reiterate what @eodabash said on 2014-04-07 was EXACTLY it.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Premium and I too lost Go To Definition functionality when the file was file containing the class was not opened.

## Resolution:

1. Tools > Options > Text Editor > File Extension
2. Notice extension, "cs" was missing from list.
3. Type, "**cs**" in the *Extension* box
4. Select, "**Microsoft Visual C#**" under *Editor*
5. Click, Add. Click, Ok.

**BOOM!**

My issue was NOT an extension. It was NOT the .suo files. It was NOT a reinstall issue. It worked in C++ but NOT C#.

**It WAS the file extensions option were not associated with C#**.  (*facepalm*)

Comment: Question, what if C# is missing?

Comment: This 1000x!!! I've tried everything and never though to check file extension association. More symptoms to help future strugglers: Peek definition _does_ work but goto definition and F12 do not work.

Comment: You are my hero dude you have no idea, how can i send you some coffee lol

Comment: @NeilBusse, that was the best response i've gotten in a long time. Just raise a cup & a head nod to the monitor, that's good enough for me.

Comment: I tried a bunch of the other potential fixes called out here and in other posts and nothing else worked besides this. No idea why this stopped working in VS 2017 15.9.6 but this fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a solution with C++ combined with C# which is set to VS 2010 compiler but I edit it with the 2013 IDE. All of this is orchestrated with the MS-TFS. I searched for both *.ncb and *.sou files but couldn't find them. Eventually I saw eodabash's comment of changing the File Extension option, and hey presto, it works for me...

Answer (score 1):

Fortran is not listed in Tools > Options > Text Editor > File Extension, so this route did not work for me.
What worked for me was:

```
Tools > Options > Text Editor > Fortran > Advanced > Enable Find All References.
```

Set the above field to True. Also

```
Tools > Options > Text Editor > Fortran > Advanced > Enable Go To Definition.
```

This field may need to be changed to true.

Answer (score 0):

For me, rebuilding the solution, then closing the file in visual studio and reopening it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the source file is part of the solution you have open. *- Sigh.*

*(For me, I was looking for 'Go to Definition' for a source file in a completely different solution than what I had opened in Visual Studio.  I opened the correct solution, verified 'Go To Definition' was functional, then grabbed a much needed cup of coffee.)*