# visual 2013 ultimate: go to declaration is not available

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I have used go to declaration to view the source code of objects/methods that are declared in the other projects within the same solution. It has been worked great. Suddenly, the go to declaration option is not available after I highlighted the method, and I don't see it in the content menu.

Note
1) I always reboot the machine every day
2) I have been working on the same project for the past few weeks. I have been working on the same solution file before and after go to declaration menu is gone

I did make  a lot change on the solution. I recompiled the object so many times. Not sure, if I accidentally cause any problem

Right now, I have to traverse to different project in the solution to find the source code.  I can also put the break point. Once the program stops at that break point, I can step into the code.

More about the project, many objects/classes and  defined in the other projects. Technically, they are external DLL. I know how to debug external dll, but it is cumbersome. Therefore, I include those projects in the solution (actually, the developers at my show include most of them. Then I included more). Go to definition always navigates back to metadata, but go to declaration will go back to the actual code. It is a wonderful tool, but I cannot see it anymore in the past few days.

Any thing I can do to revive this menu. Oh, I did try ctrl-f12. It does not work

Thanks

Comment: You can try deleting the intellisense database as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898616/visual-studio-go-to-definition-disabled-or-gray-out).

Comment: I deleted suo file (there is no ncb file). Then I reopened and rebuilt the solution. i did that couple times. The go to declaration is still not available

Answer (score 0):

Ok

I finally figured out what happened. It was resharper that was causing the problem. What happened was I had to change my machine 3 weeks ago. I slowly installed more and more software. Then I applied the product key. Then one day, the go to declaration disappeared. I did not even notice that

[Intellisense and code suggestion not working in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992983/intellisense-and-code-suggestion-not-working-in-visual-studio-2012-ultimate-rc)

The above link is the long thread that has various resolutions. Different people may encounter different issues. I have tried various resolutions (restart the visual studio, etc), and none of them work.

Resharper->Options->IntelliSense->General Set to 'Visual Studio native IntelliSense

This one works for me. Oh, you need to get your R# license to have this feature turn on