# Visual Studio 'go to definition' doesn't go to the right place

Tags: c, visual-studio

For example:
I click the 'go to definition' of this function, `cal_Q_only()`:
[image: The word '转到定义' means 'go to definition' in English].
It jumps to here, in the middle of `outsol_ambi_raim()`:
[image]
But I would expect it to instead jump to this place, the definition of `cal_Q_only()`:
[image]
Does anyone know what's wrong about it?

It's not the only wrong function, some of my function can go to the right place, most of them cannot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio “Go to definition” disabled or gray out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898616/visual-studio-go-to-definition-disabled-or-gray-out)

Answer (score 1):

I googled and I found a solution.
Go tools->options->text editor->c/c++->advanced->Recreate Database->True and restart the VS.
The 'go to definition' will work again.