# Visual c# 2010 express edition, items missing on right-click after reinstall

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've just re-installed Visual c# 2010 express edition.

On my previous install, without any special edition i had a "Go to definition" button, whenever i right clicked a method.

As you can see, now it disappeared [image]

I tinkered around the customization menus above, but they only provide commands in the main tool bar, and not on the right click.

I also tried installing 2 different versions of it, and on a computer where the old c# 2010 remains, the "go to definition" command is available when i right-click a method.

I tried exporting its settings, but no command "go to definition" appears on the new one.

How can I fix it, and how can I re-install exactly the same version of visual c# 2010 express that i have on the other computer? It's version is 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529345/visual-studio-right-click-missing-find-all-refences-and-go-to-definition-disable

Comment: Yes, i tried closing the solution, deleting the .sou file, reopening the solution and rebuild, yet it doesn't go to the definition of the method, also, f12 doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, it's unknown if it's a version problem (since I have a offline and a online one, with and without sp1), or simply application settings unrecognizable.

Follow these steps:
uninstall sp1 (using the installer)
uninstall vs2010

delete the installation folder, and the visual studio 2010 folder in the "my documents" (win7 version)

reboot and reinstall, it should be fine (i used offline installation for both vs2010 and sp1)